# For In vs While Let: Why is Swift's map implementation the way it is?

Tags: swift, functional-programming

This questions stems from a [@twostraws video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlxQPfFEP90), regarding how Apple went about implementing Sequence.map

Here's how Apple do it:

```
@inlinable
  public func map<T>(
    _ transform: (Element) throws -> T
  ) rethrows -> [T] {

    let initialCapacity = underestimatedCount
    var result = ContiguousArray<T>()
    result.reserveCapacity(initialCapacity)

    var iterator = self.makeIterator()

    // Add elements up to the initial capacity without checking for regrowth.
    for _ in 0..<initialCapacity {
      result.append(try transform(iterator.next()!))
    }
    // Add remaining elements, if any.
    while let element = iterator.next() {
      result.append(try transform(element))
    }
    return Array(result)
  }
```

I understand the brilliant use of `underestimatedCount` to reserve the capacity of the array prior to going on an append party, but I don't understand the nuts and bolts of the `for _ in` and `while let` loops at the bottom.

Why is this looping implementation more optimal than simply calling:

```
while let element = iterator.next() {
    result.append(try transform(element))
}
```

for the entirety of the `Sequence`?

------ EDIT: Further Research ------

I do understand the reasoning behind when to use `while let`, `for _ in`, and force unwrap in isolation. This question concerns why this approach of using both over just one is optimal in this scenario.

What's slightly more confusing is that when looking through more Apple code, you see that `filter` uses `while let` to iterate through its elements, but reduce uses `for element in self`, instead of creating an iterator.

So many mysteries!

Comment: Commenting rather than answering because I can't say for sure this is _why_, but note the for loop force unwraps because it can ensure the existence of an element. This may be a slight performance benefit over checking to see if every element is non-nil, which can add up over a large number of iterations.

Comment: I've mentioned [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/213879/49921) that a `for` loop is faster than a `while` loop.

Comment: @ielyamani In your example `while` was only slower because each comparison operation was calling `count`. Based on the code here, I'm sure your hypothesis is still correct, but I'm still not sure why.

Comment: @XmasRights In a `while` loop the condition is checked on each iteration. In this case `iterator.next()` is checked if it's `nil` or not

Comment: @ielyamani Oh damn - it seems so obvious now. Thanks so much!